# Php artisan not sending email

Tags: php

I want to send email from php artisan schedule.
When I try artisan command in browser, email is being sent well.
But in artisan command, it is not being send.
I am not sure why it is.

My artisan console command

UpdateBet.php

```
 protected $signature = 'update:bet';
 ....
 public function handle()
 {
      $user=User::find(680);
      Mail::to($user->email)->send(new VerifyMail(User::find(680)));
 }
```

And in my web.php

```
Route::get('/update/bet',function (){
    Artisan::call('update:bet');    
});
```

Comment: artisan command in browser? what do you mean by that?

Comment: Please provide more information. Examples. What are your inputting in your cli? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: I have artisan command to sending email.

Comment: Route::get('/update/bet',function (){
    Artisan::call('update:bet');
});

Comment: Please provide some code, show what you've done so other users can help you.
You can read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Sorry. I am new to stackoverflow, I updated my question.

Comment: Please check my code above, and let me know what is issue here.